# Looping into a list of vectors in python

Tags: python, loops

Given a list of sentences I am trying to do in a short way, get from a list the strings from a structure(list of vectors) in which the first position is the value of the string:

```
sentence_list = ['I want this',' It hurts','Life is too short as it is' ]

structure = [(1,'I want this. Not that. Right now.'), (2,'When I think about what you are doing, I wonder if you realize the effect you are having on me. It hurts. A lot.'),(3,'Life is too short as it is. In short, she had a cushion job.')]
```

The result would be a list with the values of the position 0 of the vector.

My first try:

```
result = []
    for s in sentence_list:
        for i in structure:
            if s in i[1].split('.'):
                    result.append(i[0])
```

**The Target is to improve it in a way to do it in a simple line.**

```
result
[1, 2, 3] # the result is giving the first value of the vector if the string is there..
```

Comment: So what's your question exactly ?

Comment: Im using this function in a isolate process and it's working fine but I would like to improve it in an shorter way.

Comment: For one thing, you don't need `split`

Comment: Are the two lists always going to correspond like in the example? Can you zip them together?

Comment: Yes, is going always to be in that format. list of characters and list of vectors.(numeric,string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is "how do I make it a one-liner" then the answer is:

```
result = [index for index, target in structure for sentence in sentence_list if sentence in target.split('.')]
```

but that doesn't make the code much more readable.

Comment: It was very useful, less readable but very interesting...  thx a lot!